# Google tag manager slows the website score on google insights

Tags: magento, magento2

We have a magento 2 website where we added google tag manager for google analytics and some other operations. But the problem is when we added this to our website, it slows down the website speed and website score on google insights. Is there any solution to improve website score while using google tag manage on our site?

Answer (score 0):

I have some websites with GTM installed and never faced a slow down after the installation. I would recommend you check with your host if there is an abnormal consumption from other sources.
In my experience, most of the cases are related to robots and suspicious IPs. I have installed robot blocks and visit cpanel in a daily basis for blocking suspicious IPs and countries.
I also saw a drastic increase on performance after changing my hosting plan to dedicated host with GoDaddy with 6Gb RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Via the Developer tools
You can block gtm.js in your browser developer tools. This will prevent the loading of Google tag manager and the associated tags. Once you have done this, you can run Google Lighthouse from your browser, to see how your scores improve.